# SQL Server 2008 R2 Windows authentication fails

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Windows Server 2008. I have enabled both Windows and SQL Authentication modes.

I can't connect with client PCs to the SQL Server. The following error occurs:

> Login failed. The Login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

Assuming the server name is `MyServer`, I have added the user `MyServer\Guest` but again, no results.

I was told to add the clients names as `trusted` in Windows Server. But I don't know if it works and if yes I don't know how to do this.

I also disabled firewall and enabled named pipes in case it matters.

Comment: What are you using to connect to the server? Is it an application, a web site, SQL Management Studio?

Comment: *The Login is from an untrusted domain* - does this mean that your server and your client are in different domains?

Comment: There is an application written in Delphi 2010. all systems are in the same domain and WORKGROUP. I see this error even if I try to connect with another SQL Management Studio.